# How to show a custom error message in DropzoneJS?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I need to check if a file has a valid MIME type, if the file size is ok and if its dimensions are ok, then upload file.

So when everything is OK, I can use:

```
complete: function(file){
    // do something here.
}
```

but what if the size of file was invalid? In my PHP script I return an error message:

```
return json_encode(['error' => 'size is invalid']);
```

OR

```
return Response::json(['error' => 'size is invalid'], 500 ];
// this is Laravel 4 syntax. returns a json array and 500 as status code.
```

but how can I handle that `error` in DropzoneJS?

I tried adding a second parameter to the `complete()` function but it's not working.

```
complete: function(file, response){
    console.log( response ); // this does not work.
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the response after the file was submitted to server use this in DropzoneJS:

```
success: function(file, response) {
  alert(response);
}
```

And to validate the file before uploading it use this:

```
complete: function(file) {
  if (file.size > 3.5*1024*1024) {
     alert("File was Larger than 3.5Mb!");
     return false;
  }

  if(!file.type.match('image.*')) {
    alert("Upload Image Only!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

If your server is returning `response` in `JSON`, you'll need to use `JSON.parse` before `alert`ing it.

Hope it'll help you! Cheers! :)

Comment: Just to add something I think is useful: you should listen to events (http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_8) not rewriting it (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/297). Cheers! :)

Comment: @amandasantanati That Really good indeed, it'll allow you to add more functionality. +1 for links.

Comment: To check file's format it's also usefull to use `Dropzone.isValidFile(file, this.options.acceptedFiles)`. This validates against the settings you set on initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Just to simplify what @amandasantanati said so you don't click around:

Don't do `complete: ...` but instead:

```
init: function() 
    {
        this.on("complete", function(file) {
            if (file.size > 3.5*1024*1024) {
                this.removeFile(file);
                alert('file too big');
                return false;
            }

            if(!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                this.removeFile(file);
                alert('Not an image')
                return false;
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the HTTP response code
http_response_code(415); // Unsupported Media Type
or http_response_code(415); // Not Acceptable

```
    function showError($message)
    {
        http_response_code(415);
        die($message);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is always better to validate before upload, so use 'error' event like this:

```
        myDropzone.on('error', function (file) {

        if ((file.size / 1024 / 1024) > this.options.maxFilesize) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            alert('error');
        }

    });
```

if you still want to handle this after upload, you can send the response from controller like:

```
<?php return Response::json(['error' => 'size is invalid'], 400 ]; ?>
```

and handle the response like:

```
myDropzone.on('error', function (file, response) {

if(typeof response =="object"){
        alert(response.error);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DropzoneJS expects the server's response to be text and not JSON, which is why 'object Object' appears since it is placing the content directly in the HTML element. To make DropzoneJS display your error message instead of 'object Object', you can do this:

```
 myDropzone.on('error', function (file, response) {
     if(typeof response =="object"){
        file.previewElement.children[3].innerText = response.error //Text
     }
 });
```

I think people misunderstood your question because the answers here don't give exactly what was asked, so I posted the solution to give some direction to those who are lost.